# What's the relationship between Matrix Space and Inner Product Space

Tags: matrices

[image: Definition of Matrix Space]

[image: Inner Product Space]

Here, from my perspective, these two definitions imply that an inner product space is a subset of a space where the function p is a symmetric bi-linear form (we can denoted this space by (X,p)). Next, (X,p) is a subset of matrix space. Are there any mistakes in my understanding?

Moreover, a Lemma says that
[image: Lemma]
So, how to understand this Lemma? How to prove a matrix space described above is an inner product space?

Comment: Dear J.Bao, I see you have not accepted an answer to any of your questions. Please consider doing so by clicking the check mark '✓' next to your preferred answer.

Comment: No, an inner product space is a vector space with some additional structure. It’s not necessarily a subset of anything. The same goes for a metric space—it’s a vector space equipped with an extra function that has certain properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note the term is 'metric space' and not 'matrix space'.

Second, the excerpts you cite are saying that an inner product on a real vector space can be used to define a metric on the same space.

Third, the converse implication in your last sentence is not true. There is *no* way in general to produce an inner product given a metric.

Comment: And in fact, many metrics don't even come from inner products. This is shown with the parallelogram law.

Comment: @CameronWilliams certainly, though perhaps it would be more accurate to say not every metric comes from a norm and not every norm comes from an inner product. The parallelogram law is the only obstruction to the latter.

Comment: Very good point!